# Multisite drupal bootstrap

Tags: 7, bootstrapping

Is it possible to bootstrap a particular drupal 'settings.php' ?

I've gotten bootstrap to work with the default site only.

Comment: have you read the comments regarding this inside `settings.php` and then called `drupal_bootstrap()` etc from the actual directory containing the non-default site?

Comment: @Jimajamma good call- I had not. I am going to try to use the PHP's `chdir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this code:

```
chdir('/path/to/drupal/sites/example.com/');
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/path/to/drupal/core');
require_once('/path/to/drupal/includes/bootstrap.inc');
drupal_override_server_variables(array('url' => 'http://example.com/'));
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

It could perhaps be more efficient but it works from crontab.

Comment: And the URL of the script needs to be the site name as well. For example, if you have a script at `http://default.com/script.php` but it's trying to load a non-default site `other.com` you'll need to use `http://other.com/script.php`. If running from the command line then I don't know